# Can't deserialize JSON string by the help of System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json

I can't get System.Text.Json deserialization to work.

```
    public class LoginResponse
    {
        public LoginResponse()
        {

        }

        [JsonPropertyName("token")]
        public string Token;
    }
```

Example response from webservice which I want to deserialize:

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImdvZG90IiwiZXhwIjoxNjQ2MDExODU1LCJpYXQiOjE2NDYwMTE1NTV9.tNtSWreYQjVxTuIFtzXdEWDY5Tr9I2tBI5D8gSR8FUTBDdsFKifzkHbYAshwxplQJc9m7e-1BxT3iV2_pQ7Uhw"}
```

But responseBody.Token remains empty:

```
var responseBody = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LoginResponse>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body));
```

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don’t think it works with fields. Try a property instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, System.Text.Json doesn't support binding to fields. You could change   `Token` in your model to a property:

```
[JsonPropertyName("token")]
public string Token { get; set; }
```

If you're using .NET 5 or above you could use `[JsonInclude]` attribute on public fields:

```
[JsonInclude]
[JsonPropertyName("token")]
public string Token;
```